# Working with images in asp.net MVC ViewMasterPage in design mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

While designing a master page i am adding a number of images to it.

I have an image tag inside the master page,

```
<img src="../../Content/Images/img19.jpg" class="profileImage" />
```

When i run my app, the image doesn't show up in the browser because the src path in the page that browser gets is same as in the master page.

ie. "../../Content/Images/img19.jpg"

But it should have been "Content/Images/img19.jpg"

If i correct the src path in master page as

```
<img src="Content/Images/img19.jpg" class="profileImage" />
```

Then I can see the image in the browser but not in design mode.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Asp Images

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/Pictures/xxx.png" />
```

You will see images in design mode and when you publish Pages too.

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want to introduce extraneous server controls into an MVC site?

Comment: hmm.. Why not? Is it very big problem?

Comment: At best, it's just unnecessary and confusing. At worst, you will not get the result you intend. MVC doesn't use the same postback mechanism or page cycle as traditional Web Forms. There is no reason to have an image tag live in a server control in the MVC framework. Granted, this example will work because it just renders as an image tag, but it goes against the purpose of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine if you use a leading slash:

```
<img src="/Content/Images/img19.jpg" class="profileImage" />
```

For other situations, you can convert a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path using Url.Convert, such as

```
Url.Content("~/Content/Images/img19.jpg");
```